# Persistent: Convert Text to Key

Tags: mysql, haskell, persistent, yesod

I'm using persistent and persistent-mysql. I have a Monad SqlM

```
type SqlM a = SqlPersist (ResourceT IO) a)
```

Inside my function

```
testFun :: T.Text -> SqlM ()
testFun someId = ...
```

I can query the Database by using

```
entity <- selectFirst [SomeField ==. someId]
```

But I would like to select entitys by ID. I have to convert/pack someId to the Key - Type. I know this isn't the way to do it, but i tried:

```
entity <- get $ Key { unKey = PersistInt64 (read $ T.unpack someId) }
```

this fails with:

```
Couldn't match type `PersistEntityBackend
                       (Entity (DBTableGeneric backend0))'
              with `Database.Persist.GenericSql.Raw.SqlBackend'
The type variable `backend0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Expected type: Key (Entity (DBTableGeneric backend0))
  Actual type: KeyBackend
                 Database.Persist.GenericSql.Raw.SqlBackend
                 (Entity (DBTableGeneric backend0))
In the second argument of `($)', namely
  `Key {unKey = PersistInt64 (read $ T.unpack someId)}'
```

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use [fromPathPiece](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130301-40/path-pieces/Web-PathPieces.html#v%3afromPathPiece) for this kind of conversion. As for your error message, you can probably just add a type signature to clarify to the compiler what types you're working with.

Comment: What do I have to add the type signature to? I tried to add it to the key _KeyBackend SqlBackend entity_ but i still get the error shown above.

Comment: Try something like `(fromPathPiece someId :: Maybe DBTableId)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast help, that did the job!