# Couldn't match type ‘Text’ with ‘Key Todos’ arising from a use of ‘TodosId’

Tags: haskell, cabal, ghci

I try to create a Scotty Web app with CRUD operations.
I can do the get operation to fetch all the todos list

```
getTodos :: ActionM ()
getTodos = do
  (todos :: [Entity Todos]) <-
    liftIO $ inBackend $ selectList [] []
  json todos
```

But I am blocked in my get operation to fetch only one item by id (which is a uuid value)

```
getTodo :: ActionM ()
getTodo = do
  (id :: Text) <- param "id"
  (todos :: [Entity Todos]) <-
    liftIO $ inBackend $ selectList [TodosId ==. id][]
  json todos
```

I got this message from "cabal run" command:

```
app/Main.hs:133:38: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Text’ with ‘Key Todos’
        arising from a use of ‘TodosId’
    • In the first argument of ‘(==.)’, namely ‘TodosId’
      In the expression: TodosId ==. id
      In the first argument of ‘selectList’, namely ‘[TodosId ==. id]’
```

I have tried to find a code to create a Persistent "Key" value to use in "selectList [TodosId ==. id][]" but all my test failed.

I am using

```
Cabal ==3.8.1.0,
scotty ==0.20.1,
persistent ==2.14.6.0,
persistent-postgresql ==2.13.6.1,
```

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330294/persistent-convert-text-to-key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to share the solution:

```
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
import Web.PathPieces

parseNewsId :: Text -> TodosId
parseNewsId =
    fromJust . fromPathPiece

getTodo :: ActionM ()
getTodo = do
  (id :: Text) <- param "id"
  (todos :: [Entity Todos]) <-
    liftIO $ inBackend $ selectList [TodosId ==. (parseNewsId id)][]
  json todos
```

And can get the result as expected

```
[
    {
        "description": "it is awesome",
        "id": "4754e8n7-6e5c-1234-7894-9312071db111",
        "is_done": false,
        "name": "Do exercice haskell"
    }
]
```

Thanks for your attention!